# Plotly Legent Aa labels how to remove them

Tags: python, plotly

I am using a scatter plot with mode = markers+text. The legends appear with this disturbing Aa label. Anyway to remove them? I am using plotly for python

[image]

Comment: Share a basic working example code with the issue!!!

Comment: i think the information provided is adequate for plotly users. Found the answer here :https://community.plot.ly/t/editing-the-legend-symbols/2113. Thank you for taking a look though.

Comment: If you solved your issue, you can answer your own question and close this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certanly not the right way to perform the task, but if you want to render images using Orca - there is no other option.

1. Locate `plotly.min.js` (`plotly.io.to_image()` use internal library at
   site-packages\plotly\package_data)
2. Find and replace `x.tx="Aa"` to `x.tx=""`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately removing Aa label when using mode = markers+text is not available in plotly

Found the answer [here](https://community.plot.ly/t/editing-the-legend-symbols/2113)

Comment: Thanks, adding g.pointtext {
display: none;
} to the css helped for me